# Установка Eclipse без UDP

Tags: eclipse

Пытаюсь поставить последнюю верию Eclipse на Ubuntu 14.04. С оф. сайта скачивается инсталлер, который пытается скачать из Интернета какой-то файл, однако испытывает проблемы с подключением. Я думаю что эти проблемы возникают из-за того, что провайдер запрещает UDP подключения. Можно ли подцепить искомый файл скачав его другим способом и перебросив через флешку либо заставить инсталлер использовать TCP для подключения (он точно работает).

Comment: Эклипс без инсталятора обычно ставиться. Обычный архив. Скачайте полную версию которую вам надо, то есть сборку под ваши нужды.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, вот почему-то никак не могу найти на их сайте ссылку на архив без инсталлера...

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Luna/SR2 Вот например.